# Pentaho job "Hadoop File Output" writing onto pentaho server instead of HDFS path

Tags: hadoop, pentaho

I am using the "Hadoop File output" component. Sometimes it works correctly but sometimes it tries to write the file on pentaho server itself. Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: Do you mean DI server?

Comment: Yes it is creating similar path in its installation path